# GNU compiler below the required version

Tags: gcc, versions, compiler, gnu

I'm obtaining this error message: GNU 7.5.0 compiler is below the minimum required version 8.0.0
even though when I type "sudo apt install gcc-8 g++-8", I obtain an output saying that gcc 8 is already installed but when I check the version of gcc using "gcc --version" I see that it is 7.5.0
what can I do to install the latest version?

Comment: What's the context here? If you are building software, it's often possible to select the compiler to use via build flags or environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have both `gcc-7` and `gcc-8` installed, `gcc-7` is the one being used when you run gcc, lets change this by using `update-alternatives` to change the default `gcc` to `gcc-8`.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 7

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8 8


sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Comment: The alternatives should be already installed, so just the `--config` should be needed.

Comment: I am obtaining this error:
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc
:(

Comment: I just added a step to do before, try again

Comment: okay thank you.
I just have one more question, it keeps telling me that low disk space on filesystem root, although when I look into my PC on windows I see that there is 8 GB free space. What can I do? I need free space on ubuntu to work on a simulator and run scripts

Comment: Also when I shutdown the VM and reopen VMware workstation and start Ubuntu the screen keeps stuck on a black screen and Ubuntu doesn't open... It happened several times and I was obligated to delete the VM and recreate a new one and repeat everything from start

Comment: The partition in which your root filesystem is located is running out of space, for the black screen it could be due to a problem such as graphics driver issues or problems with the VM settings